# Нужна ли точка после номера телефона?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть. Имеется текст рекламы: описание услуг, а в конце номер телефона в таком виде: Тел.: (000)000000000. Ставится ли точка после номера телефона или она там не нужна?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А почему не должно быть точки? Хотя я специально посмотрела рекламные объявления - точки нигде не ставят, но это ничего не значит. В конце обязательно должен быть знак препинания. Моё мнение такое.